# Asp net core bad model in parameter at post action is not set to null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, parameters

I have this problem I'm following the Api course on pluralsight and I've been trying to understand why when I pass an invalid Dto in a post request it doesn't get set to null.
Here is my Dto

```
public class AuthorCreateDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public int GenreId { get; set; }

    public int CountryId { get; set; }
}
```

and action

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<AuthorDto> CreateAuthor([FromBody]AuthorCreateDto authorCreateDto)
    {
        if (authorCreateDto == null)
            return BadRequest();

        var author = Mapper.Map<Author>(authorCreateDto);

        if (TryValidateModel(author))
            return BadRequest();

        var newAuthor = _authorService.CreateAuthor(author);

        var newAuthorDto = Mapper.Map<AuthorDto>(newAuthor);

        return CreatedAtRoute("GetAuthor", new { id = newAuthor.Id }, newAuthorDto);
    }
```

so when I post an invalid json as

`{
    "epa": 2,
    "wdawd": "awdawd"
}`

authorCreateDto does not get set to null while on the course it does. Idk whats going on thank you

Comment: What is the argument value of the authorCreateDto parameter than?

Comment: How are you posting this object?

Comment: Are you using the same version of ASP.NET Core as the course?

Comment: No, I'm using the 2.1 sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Asp.Net Core, its built-in serializer is `Newtonsoft.Json` and for `FromBody`, it will use `JsonInputFormatter` to bind the request body to model.

By default, `SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling` is `Ignore` which return default value for the properties which is missing in the request body.

If you prefer `null` for `authorCreateDto`, you could configure it with `Error` by

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => {
                    options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.MissingMemberHandling.Error;
                });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!